# zend framework 2 Route/Virtual Host

Tags: php, zend-framework

How do i create a route and make it work without have to create a virtual Host in Zend Framework 2?

Hello to all,
I currently a newbie in PHP + Zend Framework 2. I have been hitting my head on the wall for a month now. Reading tutorial after tutorial on how to create routes in Zend Framework 2.The problem is every tutorial i read must create a virtual host in the host file.I wanted to have a route work without having to set up a virtual host.Is this possible and can anybody guide me on how it can be done.
                                    Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ms. Nehal i am currently doing this tutorial: http://bigemployee.com/zend-framework-2-simple-web-application-crud-using-ajax-tutorial/ .However i wanted to know the relationship between Virtual host and Route(module.config) and if i can set a route without using Virtual host. :\

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in zend documentation here https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-built-in-php-cli-server you can use the built-in CLI server using command

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
```

to do this just open your command prompt and type above command there and then after -t put full path of your project's public folder like if you save your project in c:\wamp\www\Myproject\public then type whole path there after a space put the path again pointing to your index.php file like this  c:\wamp\www\Myproject\public\index.php  So your final command will be like this.

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t c:\wamp\www\Myproject\public\ c:\wamp\www\Myproject\public\index.php
```

then hit enter. Now go to your browser and type this url http://localhost:8080/.
That's it, But don't close command prompt otherwise you will not able to open your project. One more thing you need to run this command every time you run your project.

I hope this will help you

Comment: if i have this virtual host config:<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stickynotes.local
    DocumentRoot my/project/dir/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development" // make sure to set the application environment
</VirtualHost>

Comment: using this command you don't need to setup virtual host.
you only need to run this command. This is an alternative if you don't want to setup virtualhost

Comment: i was trying to follow this tutorial:http://bigemployee.com/zend-framework-2-simple-web-application-crud-using-ajax-tutorial/ but hostname(stickynotes.local)takes me to localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: It is expected behavior. Is your project running or not?

Comment: Directory C:\wamp\www\StickyNotes\Public does not exist. However this path does exist...

Comment: where you save your project. are you using wamp server or xampp server?
Please make sure you give right path of your project